# Render captions above figures with \caption below \includegraphics while using endfloat

Tags: floatrow, endfloat, apa7

**Background**: My TeX file is generated from R Markdown and captions are automatically placed below included figures. Here is a minimal example of what my generated TeX file looks like:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum

\begin{figure}
The figure
\caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Problem**: Figure captions need to be rendered *above* the corresponding figure (as per APA guidelines) without moving `\caption`.

**What I have tried**: I understand that captions can be rendered above the figure without changing the code via the `floatrow` package and `\floatsetup[figure]{style=plaintop}`. However, loading `floatrow` interferes with `endfloat`, which is loaded by `apa7`. Specifically, figures are no longer placed at the end of the document but rendered in place:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plaintop}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum

\begin{figure}
The figure
\caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

According to the documentation of `endfloat`, `floatrow` should always be loaded before `endfloat` (and, thus, before `apa7`). Hence, I try to load `floatrow` via `\RequirePackage{}` but this yields errors. I can fix some of those by undefining two lengths, but this leaves me with the following error that I can't seem to resolve:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \@classoptionslist 
l.1453 \ProcessOptionsWithKV{floatrow}
```

Here's the minimal reproducible example:

```
\RequirePackage{floatrow}
\let\abovecaptionskip\undefined
\let\belowcaptionskip\undefined

\documentclass{apa7}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Note that despite the error message I get a rendered PDF file that looks as expected. Also this is not specific to `apa7`; I get the same error when I use the `article` or `book` document class.

Comment: What's the reason for trying to load the package before `\documentclass`?

Comment: `apa7` loads `endfloat` to place figures at the end of the document. When I load `floatrow` after `\documentclass` and, thus, after loading `endfloat`, figures are rendered in place rather than being delayed.

Comment: Note that if you use `floatrow` just for caption position then you can also do this by just entering the caption before the float, e.g., `\begin{figure}\caption{xyz}\includegraphics{}\end{figure}`, then you don't need to load `floatrow` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just updated my question to provide more context and a more detailed description of the problem. As noted, my TeX is automatically generated, so I don't have control over the placement of `\caption` inside the figure environment.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, apa7 converts `figure` into `figure*`.  Anyway, the basic idea is to store the caption and figure into separate saveboxes and reverse their order.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

% udbox is a \vbox version of lrbox
\makeatletter
\def\udbox#1{%
  \edef\reserved@a{%
  \endgroup
  \setbox#1\vbox{%
  \begingroup\aftergroup}%
  \def\noexpand\@currenvir{\@currenvir}%
  \def\noexpand\@currenvline{\on@line}}%
  \reserved@a
  \@endpefalse
  \color@setgroup
  \ignorespaces}
\def\endudbox{\unskip\color@endgroup}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\mycaptionbox}
\newsavebox{\myfigurebox}

\makeatletter
\let\normalmakecaption=\@makecaption
\def\@makecaption#1#2{\def\test{figure}%
  \ifx\@captype\test \global\setbox\mycaptionbox=\vbox{\normalmakecaption{#1}{#2}}%
  \else \normalmakecaption{#1}{#2}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\let\normalfigure=\figure
\let\endnormalfigure=\endfigure

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][tbp]{\normalfigure
  \begin{udbox}{\myfigurebox}}%
{\end{udbox}\unvbox\mycaptionbox
  \unvbox\myfigurebox\endnormalfigure}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\normalfigurestar\csname figure*\endcsname
\expandafter\let\expandafter\endnormalfigurestar\csname endfigure*\endcsname

\renewenvironment{figure*}[1][tbp]{\normalfigurestar
  \begin{udbox}{\myfigurebox}}%
{\end{udbox}\unvbox\mycaptionbox
  \unvbox\myfigurebox\endnormalfigurestar}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum

\begin{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `efloat` package is doing its re-definitions of `figure`, `figure*` etc. inside `\efloat@AtBeginDocument`, and usually `\efloat@AtBeginDocument` is defined as either `\@iden` or `\AtBeginDocument`. In this case both would do the re-definitions too early since the `floatrow` package does its re-definitions `\AtBeginDocument`. So the trick to get your situation solved is to delay the re-definitions done by the `endfloat` package even further.

Luckily the definition of `\efloat@AtBeginDocument` is done with `\providecommand` since the author of `efloat` already had in mind to give the user an option to self-determine the exact moment when the re-definitions should be done: "(Note: \efloat@AtBeginDocument will be defined using \providecommand so document classes and packages can pre-define it if needed.)" (Quote taken from the `efloat` code documentation)

The solution below defines its own version of `\efloat@AtBeginDocument`, storing the content into a macro called `\efloatredefinitions` which could be applied later on, especially after the re-definitions of the `floatrow` package were already done.

```
% Store the code of efloat re-definitions into \efloatredefinitions
% (This code must be defined before the efloat package is loaded.)
\makeatletter
\newcommand\efloatredefinitions{}
\newcommand\efloat@AtBeginDocument{\g@addto@macro\efloatredefinitions}
\makeatother

\documentclass[man]{apa7}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plaintop}

% Do the efloat re-definitions after the re-definitions of floatrow were done
%\show\efloatredefinitions
\AtBeginDocument{\efloatredefinitions} % or simply \efloatredefinitions after \begin{document}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum

\begin{figure}
The figure
\caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: It would be nice if the `endfloat` package would offer an option "storeredefinitions" or similar so `\PassOptionsToPackage{storeredefinitions}{endfloat}` could be used instead of defining `\efloat@AtBeginDocument` on its own. Will write an e-mail to the author of `endfloat` about this...

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!