# Latex - Suppressing a Piece of Tex Output, but keeping numbering etc throughout for Book for example

Tags: output

I am using a trick I found here to suppress text output when I wish.  See below.  The only problem is that 1.  My equations are still showing (not suppressed) and 2.  My tables show the \hlines.  How can I modify this to get rid of those as well.

Note:  My purpose is to run a chapter, but eliminate some material from the output, but still retain the number of tables, figures, equations intact for the part that I do output.

Thanks, Lucas

```
\documentclass{article}
\long\def\suppress#1\endsuppress{%
  \begingroup%
    \tracinglostchars=0%
    \let\selectfont=\nullfont
    \nullfont #1\endgroup}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \suppress
  This text will not be seen in the generated document.
  \endsuppress
  But this text will.
  \suppress
  And this text won't again.
  \endsuppress
\end{document}
```

Comment: You say "chapter", but `article` doesn't have chapters; `book` does.  Does your suppression change happen at page breaks (such as between chapters)?  If so, I would recommend looking into `include` and `includeonly`, which is designed with exactly this in mind.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into that.  The problem is that I want to split up chapters as well.  so that would require making many subdivisions of chapters - which is annoying.

Comment: Why don't you just `\usepackage{comment}` https://ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en ?

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the udbox environment from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563109/render-captions-above-figures-with-caption-below-includegraphics-while-using-e/563241?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.5628#563241).  Like lrbox, it is a bit fragile.

Like any group, global changes (like `\stepcounter`) will be effected while local changes will be lost.  In addition, aux file entries (like `\label`) will be delayed until the box is printed (never).

Later: I figured a way to add `\label`s, but I had to use TikZ (which seems overkill).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\bitbucket}
\newenvironment{supress}{\begin{udbox}{\bitbucket}}%
{\end{udbox}}

\newenvironment{supress*}{\begin{udbox}{\bitbucket}}% add aux file entries
{\end{udbox}\tikz[overlay]{\node[opacity=0]{\box\bitbucket};}}

\makeatletter
\def\udbox#1{% fragile
  \edef\reserved@a{%
  \endgroup
  \setbox#1\vbox{%
  \begingroup\aftergroup}%
  \def\noexpand\@currenvir{\@currenvir}%
  \def\noexpand\@currenvline{\on@line}}%
  \reserved@a
  \@endpefalse
  \color@setgroup
  \ignorespaces}
\def\endudbox{\unskip\color@endgroup}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \begin{supress}
  This text will not be seen in the generated document.
  \end{supress}
  But this text will.
  \begin{supress}
  And this text won't again.
  \end{supress}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The common use case that you allude to is chapters of a book.  In that case, you should look into `\include` and `\includeonly`.  `\include` works like `\input`, but also processes the aux file, so that the counters correctly update.  This means that once you `\include` a file, you can omit it from the `\includeonly` as long as it doesn't change.  The main thing to be aware of is that `\include` will cause a page break.  For this reason, it's most often used for chapters of a book.

```
\documentclass{book}
\includeonly{chapter2file} % comma separated list (or comment out to have everything)
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \include{chapter1file} % not seen in the generated document
  \include{chapter2file} % But this text will
  \include{chapter3file} % And this text won't again
\end{document}
```

where each `chapter#file` has everything from `\chapter{Chapter Title}` through the end of that chapter.

This would also work for individual sections, but it sounds like your use case would involve too many files to be worthwhile.