Hide questions when \printanswers is used in the exam document class
As an alternative for my earlier asked question I would like the questions of my exam entirely be hidden when \printanswers is used. So, only the solutions will be printed.
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\printanswers

%SOLUTIONSLAYOUT
\unframedsolutions
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\textbf{\thequestion\thepartno \quad maximumpoints \themarginpoints}\\}

%THE EXAM
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \question
    This sentence is hidden when \textbackslash printanswers is used.
        \begin{parts}
        \part[1]
        Also this, including question- and partnumber en number of points, is hidden when \textbackslash printanswers is used.
            \begin{solution}
            Only this should be printed when \textbackslash printanswers is used.
            \end{solution}
        \end{parts}   
    \end{questions}  
\end{document}


Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/619377/ could help.

@jlab Thanks, I saw that, but there's no satisfying solution so far.
