# Automaticly listing definitions at the end of document

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I'm writing latex notes for mathematics. I use `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` as an environement for definitions.

I would like to have a list of definitions at the end of the document, after a blank page. Not just the name, but the whole definition, plus the name, for each definition.

I have tried many things but I can't get it the way I want.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You can always make two copies using a savebox.  An example MWE would have been useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to do this with an environment, it is far more complicated (see [Render captions above figures with \caption below \includegraphics while using endfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563109/render-captions-above-figures-with-caption-below-includegraphics-while-using-e/563241?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C22.2526#563241)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\newsavebox{\definitions}
\newcommand{\mydefinition}[2]{\setbox0=\vbox{\begin{definition}{#1}
  #2
  \end{definition}}%
  \setbox1=\copy0
  \unvbox1
  \global\setbox\definitions=\vbox{\unvbox\definitions\unvbox0}}

\begin{document}
\section{In the beginning}

\mydefinition{Circle}{A regular polygon with an infinite number of sides.}

\mydefinition{Aristotle}{The third worst philosopher in Greek history.}

\section*{List of Definitions}
\unvbox\definitions

\end{document}
```