How can I define an environment using `fbox` and `minipage` to create a bordered area for writing my own notes?
I’m looking to create a new environment called mynote in my document to capture some of my personal thoughts. I intend to use fbox and minipage for the implementation, but there appears to be an issue with my code. Here’s my minimal working example (MWE):
%!TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[10.5pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fbox}

\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

%%% HEADER & FOOTER %%%%%
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{Header left\hfill Header right\hfill}

%%%%% TITLE %%%%%
\title{\LaTeX~Note}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}


\newenvironment{mynote}
{%
    \begin{center} % Start centered environment
        \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth} % Set content width to 90% of text width
            \small\itshape % Set content to small font and italic
            
}
{
        \end{minipage} % Close minipage
        }   
    \end{center} % End centered environment
}

%%%%% BODY %%%%%
\begin{document}

\maketitle


\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{First Section}
%% Cannot compile, there seems to be an issue with the environment definition
\begin{mynote}
    This is a note.
\end{mynote}
%% Compilable
% \begin{center} % Start centered environment
%     \fbox{
%     \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth} % Set content width to 90% of text width
%         \small\itshape % Set content to small font and italic
%         This is a note.
%     \end{minipage} % Close minipage
%     }   
% \end{center} % End centered environment
\end{document}



See the lrbox example in section 3.6 of usrguide-historic.pdf.

See also the environ package.  BTW, the source for lrbox is avilable in latex2e.pdf.

See also udbox from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563109/render-captions-above-figures-with-caption-below-includegraphics-while-using-e/563241?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C22.2526#563241

@JohnKormylo nowadays I'd prefer \NewDocumentEnvironment with the argument type b over environ (though of course environ would work as well).

If you're just interested in how you could achieve this, there are two variants, either collect the contents of the environment as an argument, or as a box. The latter has the advantage of not breaking verbatim material (but the code is more complicated).
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{pmframed}{+b}
  {%
    \begin{center}%
      \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
          #1%
      \end{minipage}}%
    \end{center}%
  }
  {}

\newsavebox\PMframedBox
\newenvironment{PMframed}
  {%
    \begin{lrbox}\PMframedBox
      \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
  }
  {%
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \begin{center}%
      \fbox{\usebox\PMframedBox}%
    \end{center}%
  }

\begin{document}
Text before the environment.
\begin{PMframed}
  This is some framed text
\begin{verbatim}
That supports a {}
nested $ verbatim
% environment
\end{verbatim}
  And additional text
\end{PMframed}
Text following the environment

Text before the environment.
\begin{pmframed}
  This is some framed text

  That doesn't support verbatim material.

  And additional text
\end{pmframed}
Text following the environment
\end{document}


Thank u so much

For simple type of ruled box, framed.sty package will helps:
%!TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[10.5pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed}

\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

%%% HEADER & FOOTER %%%%%
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{Header left\hfill Header right\hfill}

%%%%% TITLE %%%%%
\title{\LaTeX~Note}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}


%%%%% BODY %%%%%
\begin{document}

\maketitle


\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{First Section}
%% Cannot compile, there seems to be an issue with the environment definition
\begin{framed}
    This is a note.
\end{framed}

\end{document}


For complex style of Boxes, have a look at tcolorbox.sty

Thanks, I'll consider using tcolorbox
