Is that possible general method to convert an command to an environment bidirectionally?
We know that the latex-kernel provided two commands to copy the command and environment:

\NewCommandCopy
\NewEnvironmentCopy

However, a macro \cmd[#1]{#2} may gobble an optional and another mandatory argument; and an environment could also gobble an optional and another mandatory argument like \begin{myenv}[#1] #2 \end{myenv}; I wonder is there exists elegant method to convert a command to an environment and reversely.
I know that use the following like:
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmd}{+m}{%
    \begin{myenv} {#1} \end{myenv}%
}%

or:
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{+b}{%
    \cmd{#1}%
}%

may work. However, something (MAYBE) mismatch happened in the following example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
    \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
}{
    \end{minipage}
    }
}

\newcommand{\createenv}[1]{%
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
            {#1}
        \end{minipage}
    }%
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvv}{+b}{%
    \begingroup%
    \createenv{#1}%
}{\endgroup}%


\begin{document}

% \begin{myenv}%It failed with mismatch of \fbox
%     \lipsum[1]
%  \end{myenv}%

\begin{myenvv}% 
   \lipsum[1]
\end{myenvv}%

\end{document}

It raised the following error:
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\fbox  ...x {\color@begingroup \kern \fboxsep {#1}

Although the definition of myenv worked in the case, but it take two new definition and not so elegant in the case for the reason of myenvv clash with MAYBE some mismatch of the GROUPS. Is there general method to change a COMMAND to an ENVIRONMENT and change an ENVIRONMENT to a command elegantly to avoid the mismatch problem above?
I know that the definition will mismatch the groups, and I want to know how to tune the definition of myenv to fix the case here?
what's more, generally, if I want to change some commands such as \colorbox or \parbox or some commands gobble a paragraph of text, how can I change them into environment (if they can, as Ulrike Fischer's comment below). I hope that I make it clearly.
--------------------Newest Editted Version----------------------
By deeply thinking and the relative link mentioned via Skillmon, it actually solve the above problem(almost the same), just put the whole definition into the {<before>} parameters as below:
\NewDocumentEnvironment{pmframed}{+b}
  {%
    \begin{center}%
      \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
          #1%
      \end{minipage}}%
    \end{center}%
  }
  {}

instead of something below will cause the mismatch:
\newenvironment{pmframed}{%
    \begin{center}%
      \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
}{%
      \end{minipage}%
    }%
    \end{center}%
}

The above is the background, as the link in comments, it can be wrapped with lrbox or just using mdframed or tcolorbox to achieve the same result. It works! However, the MISMATCH above make my further thinking and try to make it more general, that came into the title "convert an command to an environment bidirectional":
If the syntax of one command is like \cmd{<paragraph text>} like \colorbox or \parbox, but I want to use them as an environment.
And inversely, if an environment with syntax \begin{minipage} \end{minipage} but for more convenient propose, I want to use it as \myminipage{<paragraph text>}. I think the requirement above is common(If the command don't grab commands like \verb or urls and similar that must be able to change catcodes)
For a detailed example: As I know, in tcolorbox package:

For Displayed TCB:

\newtcolorbox,\NewTColorBox for an custom environment
\NewTotalTColorBox for a custom command


For inline TCB:

\newtcbox,\NewTCBox and NewTotalTCBox for custom command



I get confused by why there is no environmant version of inline TCB(?) And more widely(generally), if ONE package provide a command with syntax of COMMAND, but I want to use it as ENVIRONMENT or bidirectionally(neglecting the case of commands will change the catcodes), what I want is the practice of the case above(both the example of minipage, and the newtcbox want to illustrate).
(still looks like an XY-problem...sobbing!But I have try my best...)
Another curiosity, thinking the relationship of commands and environments conceptionally.

environments are commands but with restrictions

Could we say:
we can change ALL environments into corresponding commands;
but only SOME commands, whose arguments will NOT change catcodes could be transformed into environments?
Best wishes to all of your sincereness and kindness.

Environments are commands, with some restirctions.  For example, instead of \begin{minipage} and \end{minipage} one can use \minipage and \endminipage.  All environments must be groups and set \currentenv inside the group.  Note that lrbox must be used with \begin and \end.

your myenv clearly can not work you have \fbox{%     \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth} } so the content of the fbox is just \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth} with no end environment. that is why the b option was introduced so you can use \fbox{\begin{minipage}{..}#1\end{minipage}}  but as you already know of the b option it is not clear what your question is?

@DavidCarlisle I am not familiar with the lrbox. As @JohnKormylo mentioned, is that every environ ment has relative begin and end commands like minipage? I know that I should use the b option, but I want some detailed information about lrbox and how to tune the definition of myenv.

The main point of an environment is that they can contain stuff between the begin and end that you do not want to be grabbed directly as an argument (as it e.g. contains commands like \verb or urls and similar that must be able to change catcodes). So no, you can not convert every environment into a command.  Or if you do you must add options like the fragile in beamer that works around this restrictions.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/733870/how-can-i-define-an-environment-using-fbox-and-minipage-to-create-a-bordered/733872#733872

can you explain why you want to do this? it looks very much like an XY-problem ....

@cfr I'm sob to make it like XY-problem, I will try my best to modify it.

It's still not clear why you want to do this.  Is this an idle curiosity?  Or is there a specific command you would like to turn into an environment (or vice versa)?  Or just why is there no inline TCB environment (because "inline environment" is a contradiction in terms)?

@Teepeemm Thanks for your advice very much, what I want is a more general transformation method of commands and environments(rooted in the above question of definition a command-like macro as environment) I will think the real example of my next question(NOT just idle curiosity) Thanks to everyone pay attention to this. And I want to store the comments above, what operation should I do, instead of just deleteing?

Macros in LaTeX cause TeX to grab tokens for macro arguments from the token stream while \begin-commands of scope-environments (\begin and \end are macros which take arguments that denote the environment-name) open a new scope, do some settings within that scope and \end-commands of scope-environments close the scope. Seems what you want is misusing the concept of scope-environments for grabbing the tokens forming the body of an instance of an environment as macro argument.

With scope-environments that don't disable the escape-character or don't disable all active characters one could hide both \begin-commands and \end-commands of scope-environments within the expansion-cascade of arbitrary sequences of (expandable) tokens. So actually with scope-environments in most cases you cannot even safely predict what tokens a user might have defined and used for delimiting the body of an instance of that scope-environment.
